# Xcode - Image view not hiding

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4.5

I have an image view in a basic app that I am attempting to set to hidden on load using:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    my_image.hidden = YES;
}
```

This code along with some other attribute changes are not functioning at all. I have synthesized the my_image property. Any ideas why this may not be working? Also, please let me know if you need any further information. I'm new to this and it's really bugging me, so thanks in advance!

Comment: [my_image.view removeFromSuperview]; may work for you.

Comment: Verify with the debugger that my_image is not nil. Views are lazy loaded and this might be your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to make it clear with a simple code line, `my_image.hidden = YES;`
But I think you can do the things below :

1. Print the imageView (your 'my_image' object) in the console to look into it.
2. Use the other properties of the imageView to see if you can manipulate it, such as changing the frame, setting the background color, or setting an image for it. If you can change the frame, then you may set `my_image.hidden = NO;` somewhere else.
3. Create another UIImageView object and add try it!
4. If none of above works, you can set the frame of 'my_image' to CGRectZero to hide it.

Comment: I've come across an interesting find... I was able to get this working by simply double clicking the image view before connecting it via an IBOutlet. Not sure why this works, but I've chosen your answer because it helped me stumble into this solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you forgot to connect the IBOutlet ? Are you using .xib ?

Comment: I did connect it, and it generated the following code `@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *my_image;`

Comment: hmm, that strange then, however if you want to hide it only in viewDidLoad, you can do it directly via the interface builder (that doesn't solve the problem if you want to show to programatically later). Btw I think it's better to use (strong, nonatomic) for IBOutlet.

Comment: Yeah, that's the thing... I'm going to need to do this programmatically later.

Answer (score 1):

make a breakpoint at line of my_image.hidden = YES; Does it go into the breakpoint ? If it goes into , make sure the my_image is not nil.

Answer (score 1):

```
UIImageView *imageview = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
[imageview setHidden:YES];
```

Comment: Please avoid code only answers. Add an explanation of what the code is doing too.

Answer (score 0):

Setter worked for me:

```
UIImageView * bb = (UIImageView*)[self.view viewWithTag:1];
[bb setHidden:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with hiding the image view but if you remove the @property statement the hidden behaves as it it should.
Set the hidden in viewdidLoad then the IBaction - works fine

.h

```
 IBOutlet UIImageView *crackedimage1;
```

.m

```
 -(void)viewdidLoad
   crackedimage1.hidden = YES;

 - (IBAction)crackaction1:(id)sender {


   crackedimage1.hidden   = NO;};
```